# Calling a function on a single instance?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `tableViewController` that displays a popup. When the popup is dismissed I need animations to occur in `tableViewController`. I am calling it with `TableViewController().test()` but it is presenting a 'found nil' error. I am guessing this is because I am instantiating a new instance, how do I go about calling the function on the existing viewController?

```
      class TableViewController {
        func showPopup() {
            let popup : PopupViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
            self.presentOnRoot(with: popup)
        }

        func test() {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.button1.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -60)
            })
        }
      }


     //Separate View Controller
      class PopupViewController {
        static func closePopup(outOfIsEditing: Bool) {
            if outOfIsEditing == true {
                TableViewController().test()
            }
        }
      }


     //Extension that displays the popup
      extension UIViewController {
        func presentOnRoot(`with` viewController : UIViewController){
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hi @mink23. I think you should create instance of an object TableViewController `var tableController =  TableViewController()` and then call `tableController.test()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a dismiss callback in `PopupViewController` and implement it inside the presenter i.e, `TableViewController` as below and get rid of the `static` approach.

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {

    public var onDismiss: (() -> Void)?

   // Using dismiss callback to notify the subscriber
    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: self.onDismiss)
    }

  // rest of your code
}
```

Implement `onDismiss` callback in `TableViewController`

```
class TableViewController {

    func showPopup() {
        let popup : PopupViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
        popup.onDismiss = {[weak self] in
            self?.test()
        }
        self.presentOnRoot(with: popup)
    }

  // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the instance calling the function to apply the animation to,

```
class PopupViewController {
       static func closePopup(outOfIsEditing: Bool, for view: UIViewController) {
           if outOfIsEditing == true {
               view.test()
               }
           }    
}
```

**Usage** : `PopupViewController.closePopup(outOfIsEditing: true, for: self)`

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this we usually create a static property to "current instance". It makes most sense to assign it on view did load. Something like the following should do:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    private(set) static var currentInstance: TableViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableViewController.currentInstance = self
    }

}
```

Now you can anywhere call

```
TableViewController.currentInstance?.test()
```

Be aware that this then only works for 1 view controller at the time. If you have multiple only the last one will be effected.

Also this may present a memory leak if you need to clear it. For instance if you dismiss this view controller it will not be visible to the user but it will still be retained by the property. This may or may not be desired effect. If you want to clear it automatically you can simply use a `weak` property:

```
private(set) static weak var currentInstance: TableViewController?
```